# ResourceBundle чистка .properties

Tags: i18n, java

Во время написания, изменения приложения в .properties откладывается иногда лишние и не используемые строки. Каким путем их можно *почистить*. Так чтобы не ручками, но и без потери нужных данных. Возможно ли это?

Comment: мне кажется проще написать свое решение под эти специализированные нужды. я когда что-то подобное надо было делал PropertyManager который управлял записью считыванием конфигурации. а набор параметров хранился как константы в enum.

потом проходитесь по массиву констант и считываете/записываете их значения в файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если держать где-то все активные ключи, то перенумеровав ключи через `ResourceBundle.getKeys()` можно понять какие лишние, далее транслировать в объекты `Properties` и применив `Properties.store()` вычистить ненужные.

Но имхо это все дорого, проще врукопашную через редактор.